# Let $A$ be $m\times n$ and $B$ be $n\times m$ matrix over real number with $m<n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be $m\times n$ and $B$ be $n\times m$ matrix over real number
>   with $m<n$. Then
>
> 1. $AB$ is always nonsingular.
> 2. $AB$ is always singular.
> 3. $BA$ is always nonsingular
> 4. $BA$ is always singular.

1. False, Since $A=0$, $B=0$ $\implies$ $AB=0$.
2. Need not be true. Let $x$ be $1\times n$ matrix. Since, $x x^T\ge 0$
3. Using the same reasoning 3 can be false.

What is the guarantee that $BA$ is always singular? If $A=x\neq 0, B=x^t.$ Then $BA$ is singular. How do I prove In general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$BA \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,

but $rank(BA)\le \min\{rank(A) ,rank(B) \} \le m<n$

Hence it must be singular.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $A$ is $m \times n$ and $m<n$ implies $Ax=0$ has a non zero solution, say $x_0$. The same non zero $x_o$ is the solution of $(BA)x=0$ as well! So $BA$ must be singular